# Численность больше или выше?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Предложение содержит такую фразу: **реальная численность больных диабетом в полтора-два раза больше**.
Рука потянулась исправить "больше" на "выше". Быть может, кто-то сталкивался с какими-либо рекомендациями или примерами на этот счёт... Или можно и так и так, а я выдумываю лишнее. Поделитесь мнением, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

В данном конкретном примере я бы просто заменил *численность* на *число*. На мой взгляд, это только улучшит качество фразы:

**Реальное число больных диабетом в полтора-два раза больше.**

Если же рассуждать вообще о сочетаемости слов *численность* и *большая/высокая*, то давайте посмотрим в словарь.

ЧИСЛЕННОСТЬ, -и; ж. Количество, численный состав чего-л. **Увеличение** численности поголовья скота. Общая ч. населения. (Большой толковый словарь)

Заметьте: увеличение, а не поднятие, из чего я делаю вывод, что численность должна быть большой, а не высокой. В Нацкорпусе мне удалось найти несколько примеров типа "численность ... больше", но не нашлось ни одного примера типа "численность ... выше"

На гарях численность его **больше**, чем под пологом древостоев. [Пирофитные свойства лиственницы Гмелина (2004) // «Лесное хозяйство», 2004.02.17]

В то же время в Нацкорпусе есть примеры и *большой*, и *высокой* численности, но 20:7 в пользу **большой** численности.

Comment: Да, с числом звучит лучше, но проблема в том, что в соседнем предложении уже есть "число", не очень хочется повторяться. Т. е. в тексте так: "Ежегодно сахарный диабет диагностируют у 1500–2000 человек, в том числе у 50–70 детей. Но при этом, по оценке экспертов, реальная численность больных диабетом в полтора-два раза больше".

Comment: Быть может, вообще на "реальные цифры" заменить это дело?.. Реальные цифры в полтора-два раза больше.

Comment: Строго говоря, цифры - это значки, они не могут быть большими и малыми. Допустимо, на мой взгляд, но стиль разговорный. Пожалуй, в этом конкретном контексте я бы оставил "численность...больше". Но это субъективное мнение.

Answer (score 2):

> Предложение содержит такую фразу: **реальная численность больных
>   диабетом в полтора-два раза больше.**
>
> Рука потянулась исправить "больше" на "выше".

Лучше, думаю,  обойтись без "больше" и "выше" (хотя оба этих варианта и могут быть употреблены в приведённом контексте), написав примерно так:

***...реально больных диабетом в полтора-два раза больше.***

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Из появившегося комментария в этой теме:

> Т. е. в тексте так: "Ежегодно сахарный диабет диагностируют у
>   1500–2000 человек, в том числе у 50–70 детей. Но при этом, по оценке
>   экспертов, реальная численность больных диабетом в полтора-два раза
>   больше".

Тогда, как вариант, можно так:

***…при этом, по оценке экспертов, реально*** [ может, заменить на *в действительности*? или *фактически*? или *на самом деле*?..] ***заболевает в полтора-два раза больше человек.***

Ну, или согласиться с предложенным автором вариантом, при этом предложив ему заменить слово *больных* на *заболевающих:*

***...при этом, по оценке экспертов, реальная численность заболевающих  ежегодно диабетом в полтора-два раза больше.***

Comment: Верно замечено! Всех больных или заболевающих ежегодно?  Нужно бы спросить у автора. Возможно, автор хотел сказать, что реальное общее число больных диабетом в два раза больше числа зарегестрированных больных? В любом случае исходная фраза требует переделки.

Comment: Тут возникает ещё одна проблема: эти тексты предоставляет больница, которая, судя по оригиналам, занимается копипастом из разных брошюр и буклетов, поэтому вероятность выяснить реальное значение этой фразы стремится к нулю.

Comment: В абзаце есть информация как об общем количестве больных, так и о ежегодной статистике. Покажу тогда уж и абзац: _"В Вологодской области проживает около 36 тысяч пациентов с диагнозом «сахарный диабет» 1-го и 2-го типов, около 500 из них – дети. В последнее время распространённость патологии существенно увеличивается. Ежегодно сахарный диабет диагностируют у 1500–2000 человек, в том числе у 50–70 детей. Но при этом, по оценке экспертов, реальная численность больных диабетом в полтора-два раза больше"_.

Comment: Глядя на весь абзац, можно только гадать, что автор хотел сказать. Но теперь видно, что можно и не переделывать ничего. Поэтому я бы оставил как есть — пусть читатель ломает голову :)

Comment: Можно предположить, что оба предположения верны: и общее число пациентов в два раза меньше числа реально больных, и ежегодно регистрируется только половина заболевших. Поэтому, повторяю, я бы оставил все как есть.